# query for insert into fail if the value contain '

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My insert into query fails if the data that i want to insert contains '

Here is the code:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO user (username,password,first_name,Age,race,gender,address,father_name,hpfather_no,father_occupation,father_identitycard,mother_name,hpmother_no,mother_occupation,mother_identitycard,session,batch_id,user_type,user_id) values ('$username','$password','$first_name','$Age','$race','$gender','$address','$father_name','$hpfather_no','$father_occupation','$father_identitycard','$mother_name','$hpmother_no','$mother_occupation','$mother_identitycard','$Session','$batch_id','user','$user_id')";
```

i want to insert the value ' inside the address but it will output an error which is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: I believe user is a reserved word in mySql.... also should 'user' -> '$user' in values section?

Comment: If you use prepared statements you will find that issues with quotes etc. will not be a problem.  This also solves issues with security and possible SQL injection issues.

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string($address);

Comment: thanks i used mysqli_real_escape_string it works now thank you

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145598/when-should-i-use-php-mysqli-real-escape-string-function